# Plesk Qmail Server email are deleted after POP3 access

Tags: email

I have a Rdhat + Plesk CP with Apache and Qmail server running on it.
We have hosted email accounts on the server. I can see, after outlook or any other mail client access the email from server, the email is removed from the server.

Is there any configuration in server to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that's in accordance with the pop3 standards to remove ("pop") mail messages from the server once the client has retrieved them, presumably into local storage.

I'd recommend you enable IMAP instead; as far as I'm aware it's an entirely superior protocol for most purposes.